# What is the proper term for lines of constant volume and constant enthalpy on a thermodynamic diagram?

Tags: thermodynamics, enthalpy, temperature, entropy

I know an isotherm is a line of constant temperature.
Isobar is a constant pressure line.
Isentrope is a line of constant entropy.

But what do you call a line of constant volume? An Isochore?
And what do you call a line of constant enthalpy? An "isenthalp"?

Comment: [Welcome to chemistry.SE!](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) If you had any questions about the policies of our community, please ‎visit [the help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help).

Answer (score 6):

> But what do you call a line of constant volume? An Isochore?

Correct.

> And what do you call a line of constant enthalpy?

The process is isenthalpic. More than one engineering/thermodynamic text I found by Googling indicates they are simply referred to as "isenthalpic lines." See [this](https://books.google.com/books?id=Sx7SBQAAQBAJ&pg=SA7-PA20&lpg=SA7-PA20&dq=isenthalpic+lines&source=bl&ots=xSF_BQVcwI&sig=IPZ_A05qJTbneadLLbj2IcQAhQM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=NtGfVbyABNCQyATWgK7gDg&ved=0CDYQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=isenthalpic%20lines&f=false) for example.

Comment: Logically, _isenthalp_ would be the name for an isenthalpic line, but based on a quick Googling, the English world seems to be lagging the German world in this vocabulary innovation.

Comment: Agreed on all points @Curt F.